# Better way of mapping two objects using org.mapstruct.Mapper

Tags: java, mapstruct

Let's say I have two classes I want to map. I managed to do it using two methods in my `@Mapper` from `org.mapstruct`

```
//copy all fields with same name from client.getPerson() with partialUpridClientInfoFromPerson
//than add some additional fields
default UpridClientInfo toUpridClientInfo(AccountLevel level, Client client) {
    UpridClientInfo result = partialUpridClientInfoFromPerson(client.getPerson());
    result.setAccountLevel(level);
    result.setBankCode(client.getBank().getCode());
    return result;
}

UpridClientInfo partialUpridClientInfoFromPerson(Person person);
```

Is there a way to do this better? Probably just using `@Mapping` and/or `@Named` annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's possible to do it even better, but this is a little bit better solution.

```
default UpridClientInfo toUpridClientInfo(AccountLevel level, Client client) {
    return toUpridClientInfo(level, client.getPerson(), client.getBank());
}

@Mapping(source = "level", target = "accountLevel")
@Mapping(source = "bank.code", target = "bankCode")
UpridClientInfo toUpridClientInfo(AccountLevel level, Person person, Bank bank);
```

Comment: With the current release (1.3) this is the best way to do it. In the future release it would be possible to map to the target directly. See https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1406